# Applying variable in html tag with python code

Tags: python, html

Is it possible to insert variable in html's tag?
For example:

```
def colour():
    c = np.random.uniform(0, 1) 
    c1 = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    c2 = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    r = hex(int(c*255))[2:]
    g = hex(int(c1*255))[2:]
    b = hex(int(c2*255))[2:]
    return "#" + r + g + b
code = colour()
print(code)
dis = HTML(r'<h3 style="color:{code};">This is the colour you feel like today. Like it? </h3>')
display(dis)
```

I randomly generate three colors and i want to print my sentence three time with colors generated above.I want to make a list and put three color's string form in it, then use for loop to output my answer.

Hope I explain my question cleary, and if there are any problem, i will give another explanation, thank you!

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code.  Post the _actual_ code as text.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited it, please check, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Robert 830213.  I have been searching for the same answer and I could not find it.  I am replying here to let people know that you have to be careful where you put the f-string.  It has to encompass the entire tag (here ) and also, if you have a placeholder for data such as {0}, it must be treated as an f-string variable by putting it in another set of curly braces.  Otherwise, instead of your value, it prints "0" in the table.  Also make sure to end the f-string before any format commands.

```
table += f"     <td bgcolor={row_color1} style='text-align:left'>{{0}}</td>\n".format(column.strip())
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29845993)

Answer (score -1):

Simply use an f-string, as in

```
rf'<h3 style="color:{code};">'
```

Comment: Hi, it is not working, it still show the default color, thanks for answering

Comment: Did you miss the `f` before the string?